# Creating own block environment in csquotes

Tags: citing, environments, csquotes

I'm trying to create my own blockquote environment in csquotes.

The `\blockquoteQ` command should behave like the normal `\blockquote` command but instead of typesetting the text upright and in quotation marks it should be typeset in italics and without quotation marks. The `\blockquoteQ` command is then used in my document for typesetting block quotes from ancient sources and the original `\blockquote` is used for block quotes from literature.

Two problems with the MWE still persists and I'm running out of ideas how to solve them:

1. I need to change the redefinition of the `\mkblockquote` command temporarily in the `smallquoteItalic` environment when the `\blockquoteQ` command is executed. At the moment both environments have quotation marks
2. It would be nice if `\blockquoteQ` could also have one optional parameter and one mandatory like the orignal `\blockquote`

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[]{csquotes, biblatex}

 \newenvironment*{smallquoteItalic}
   {\quote\small\itshape}
   {\endquote}
\newcommand{\blockquoteQ}[2]{{\SetBlockEnvironment{smallquoteItalic}\blockquote[#1][]{#2}}}

\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{\leavevmode\llap{,,}#1``#2#4#3}

 \newenvironment*{smallquote}
   {\quote\small}
   {\endquote}

  \SetBlockEnvironment{smallquote}

\begin{document}
     \blockquote[{\autocite[][]{}}]{A block quote of literature which should be set smaller, without italics but with quotation marks. A block quote of literature which should be set smaller, without italics but with quotation marks. A block quote of literature which should be set smaller, without italics but with quotation marks}

     \blockquoteQ{{\autocite[][]{}}}{A block quote of a source which should be set smaller and in italics but without quotation marks. A block quote of a source which should be set smaller and in italics but without quotation marks. A block quote of a source which should be set smaller and in italics but without quotation marks.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be no convenient interface to define new `\blockquote`-like commands in `csquotes`.

Here is an attempt that tries to use as much common code as possible. The core is that we use a toggle to switch the definition of `\mkblockquote` between `\blockquote` and `\blockquoteQ`.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\space#1}

\newenvironment*{smallquote}
  {\quote\small}
  {\endquote}

\SetBlockEnvironment{smallquote}

\newtoggle{csq@qquote}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{%
  \leavevmode
  \begingroup
  \iftoggle{csq@qquote}
    {\itshape}
    {\advance\csq@qlevel\@ne
     \llap{\textooquote}}%
  #1%
  \iftoggle{csq@qquote}
    {}
    {\textcoquote}%
  \endgroup
  #2#4#3}

% copy the original definition of \blockquote
\let\csqq@blockquote\blockquote

% new \blockquotes with toggles
% would be nicer with grouping, but that would mess with argument grabbing
\renewcommand{\blockquote}{\togglefalse{csq@qquote}\csqq@blockquote}
\newcommand{\blockquoteQ}{\toggletrue{csq@qquote}\csqq@blockquote}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
  \blockquote[{\autocite[cf.][12]{sigfridsson}}]{A block \enquote{quote} of literature which should be set smaller, without italics but with quotation marks. A block quote of literature which should be set smaller, without italics but with quotation marks. A block quote of literature which should be set smaller, without italics but with quotation marks}

  \blockquoteQ[{\autocite[cf.][13]{sigfridsson}}]{A block \enquote{quote} of a source which should be set smaller and in italics but without quotation marks. A block quote of a source which should be set smaller and in italics but without quotation marks. A block quote of a source which should be set smaller and in italics but without quotation marks.}

  \blockquote[{\autocite[cf.][12]{sigfridsson}}]{A block \enquote{quote} of literature which should be set smaller, without italics but with quotation marks. A block quote of literature which should be set smaller, without italics but with quotation marks. A block quote of literature which should be set smaller, without italics but with quotation marks}
\end{document}
```

[image: Three quote blocks. Blocks one and three are in upright font and with quotation marks. Block two is in italics without quotation marks.]

Comment: Great, thank you, now I understand the toogle commands of this package.