# \Cite equivalent for \textcquote

Tags: biblatex, csquotes

**edit:** *on request of the immer polite and very helpful @mico*

<strike>Author names should always start with a capital letter,</strike> My university requires names in citation call-outs to always start with a capital letter,  even when the author's name is 'van Oostrom'. Natbib=true lets me use **C**ite instead of **c**ite which basically tells latex to force a first capital letter.

Is there a way to make \textcquote behave the same way?

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}               % Nederlands
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@book{vanOostrom2013,
    langid = {dutch},
    location = {{Amsterdam}},
    title = {Wereld in Woorden},
    publisher = {{Uitgeverij Bert Bakker}},
    date = {2013},
    author = {van Oostrom, Fritz},
    options = {useprefix=true}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}               % Nederlands
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}        % Context sensitive quotation facilities

\usepackage[bibstyle=ext-authoryear,citestyle=authoryear,giveninits=true,maxnames=3,doi=false,isbn=false,dashed=false,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\space}
\SetCiteCommand{\parencite}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}  
    \item \cite{vanOostrom2013}  is not what we want. the V must always be capitalized.
    \item luckily \Cite{vanOostrom2013} will fix this for us
    \item same for \Citeauthor{vanOostrom2013}, \Citet{vanOostrom2013} and even \Autocite{vanOostrom2013}
\end{itemize}

Sometimes, however, I want to quote \textcquote*{vanOostrom2013}{Some Famous words}.
And then I would need \underline{\textit{Tectcquote}} which does not exists...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the claim that "Author names [used in citation call-outs] should *always* start with a capital letter" is correct? [emphasis added) I thought that uppercasing of "van" in "van Oostrum" and of "de" in "de Vries" should occur if a sentence *starts* with a citation call-out; e.g., "De Vries (1999) argued that ...". That's precisely what natbib's `\Citet`, `\Citealt`, and `\Citeauthor` are there for. In contrast, there should be no need to uppercase "de" in the sentence "As argued by de Vries (1999), ...".

Comment: Part of my paper was read by my promoter. He changed 'van Oostrom'  two times to 'Van Oostrom'. 1) `"this is a \textcquote" (Van Oostrom:2013:52)` and 2) `something related and Van Oostrom agreed (2013:52)`. So yes: _always_ :/

Comment: Can you imagine any circumstance in which (assuming your view that author names should always start with a capital is right, as I think it isn'=t!) the citation following a quote would not be capitalized? If not, you can replace `\cite` with `\Cite` globally: `\SetCiteCommand{\Cite}`. If you need more flexibility you will have more work to do.

Comment: @PaulStanley - check out my post history. My university has some very weird demands when it comes to citations... I do agree with you and @mico that there should be a different use between \cite and \Cite but my college does not agree :)

I changed `\SetCiteCommand{\parencite}` to `\Parencite` and that seems to do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: if you would post that as an answer, I can "solve" this question; although we agree this is not the best (or even a wanted) solution.

Comment: I think your promoter (is that a synonym for "academic adviser"?) is simply wrong. If it were true that the first letter of a citation call-out must always be uppercased, the existing citation call-out commands (such as `\citet` and `\citep`) would long ago have implemented this rule. The very fact that `\Citet` and `\Citeauthor` even exist strongly suggests that they were created to handle exceptional cases, *viz.*, citation call-outs at the beginning of a sentence. Clearly, though, you're stuck with an intransigent and dogmatic "promoter", and there's nothing you can do about it. Good luck.

Comment: translation from the university wide citation guidelines: `If the authors name starts with a lowercase (such as Fritz van Oostrom) you maintain the lower case only if you use his fullname (Fritz van Oostrom says...). In all other cases, you transform the last name to uppercase (and this is what Van Oostrom says), to avoid confusion in your text...` Yeah, it's not my professor/promoter :(

Comment: You could have saved several readers a lot of time if you had started your posting with "My university requires names in citation call-outs to always start with a capital letter" instead of "[a]uthor names should always start with a capital letter"...

Comment: You must be very fun at office parties. OP edited by your command, Sir

Comment: Note that it is *not* the `natbib=true` option that lets you use the capitalised `\Cite` commands, those are available even with the default `natbib=false`. `natbib` only enables `natbib`-like commands such as `\citep` (fot `\parencite`) and `\citet` (for `\textcite`) as well as `\citealt`, `\citealp` and a few other commands. Instead of `bibstyle=ext-authoryear,citestyle=authoryear` I would just use `style=ext-authoryear`. And for `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\space}` I would prefer `\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}` (but that should not be needed if you drop `natbib=true`).

Comment: thx @moewe for the additional information! - Works like a charm, as always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules for capitalisations of name prefixes like 'van', 'von', ... wary wildly between languages and regions. Since you load `babel` with the `dutch` option it is fair to assume you either want the Dutch spoken in the Netherlands or Flanders.

It is my understanding that **in the Netherlands** Dutch *tussenvoegsels* like 'de', 'van' and 'van der' are capitalised unless they are preceded by the first name (or name initial). To quote the slightly confusing English Wikipedia page on the subject [Tussenvoegsel](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tussenvoegsel&oldid=864349538)

> According to Dutch language rules in the Netherlands, the *tussenvoegsel* in a surname is written with a capital letter only when it starts a sentence or is not preceded by a first name or initial.

(If the *tussenvoegsel* starts the sentence then it is not directly preceded by a first name or initial anyway...)

Example from Dutch media outlets: 'vertelde historicus *Maarten van Rossem*' vs. 'historici hadden volgens *Van Rossem*' https://www.volkskrant.nl/es-b7bd1412 or 'presentatiecollega *Maarten van Rossem*' https://www.groene.nl/artikel/o-la-la vs. 'In Nederland *Van Rossem*, Tromp, Koen Koch, Von der Dunk, ...' https://www.groene.nl/artikel/wie-is-schuldig.

Cf. also https://woordenlijst.org/leidraad/16/2, https://taaladvies.net/taal/advies/vraag/433, https://onzetaal.nl/taaladvies/hoofdletters-in-namen-nynke-van-der-sluis-nynke-van-der-sluis/ and the beautiful pictures in https://zichtbaarnederlands.nl/zn/spelling-achternamen.php

**In Belgium** (Flanders) the capitalisation of the *tussenvoegsel* depends on the 'official form' of the name as on official documents like IDs or passports. It is usually stated that names do not change capitalisation All examples I found assumed that at least the first *tussenvoegsel* is capitalised at all times. It would be interesting to see how names with a lowercase `v` would be treated without first name and at the beginning of a sentence...

From this I understand that Belgian *tussenvoegsels* should be input with capital letters in the `.bib` file as well, i.e. `author = {Van Rossem, Jean-Pierre}` (this will lead Biber/BibTeX to treat the `Van` as part of the family name and not as a `prefix`, which nicely fits with all sorting rules and the interpretation of https://zichtbaarnederlands.nl/zn/spelling-achternamen.php).

---

Given all these rules it seems to me that it makes little sense to use the capitalised `\Cite` form at all times. Instead I would change the name formatting macros to apply capitalisation if needed. The following implements the rules w.r.t capitalisation used in the Netherlands as I understand them

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, giveninits=true, maxnames=3, doi=false, isbn=false, dashed=false, natbib=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\SetCiteCommand{\parencite}

\newbibmacro*{name:family}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}
       {}
       {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot
        \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}}%
  \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot}%

\newbibmacro*{name:given-family}[4]{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#2#3#1}%
  \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#2#3#1}%
  \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot\bibnamedelimd}%
  \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
    \ifdefvoid{#2}
      {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
      {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
    \ifprefchar
      {}
      {\ifuseprefix{\bibnamedelimc}{\bibnamedelimd}}}%
  \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
  \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}}

\newbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
       \mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot
       \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
       {}
       {\revsdnamepunct}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{vanOostrom2013,
  langid    = {dutch},
  location  = {Amsterdam},
  title     = {Wereld in Woorden},
  publisher = {Uitgeverij Bert Bakker},
  date      = {2013},
  author    = {van Oostrom, Fritz},
  options   = {useprefix=true}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}  
    \item \cite{vanOostrom2013}  is not what we want. the V must always be capitalized.
    \item luckily \cite{vanOostrom2013} will fix this for us
    \item same for \citeauthor{vanOostrom2013}, \citet{vanOostrom2013} and even \autocite{vanOostrom2013}
    \item but \fullcite{vanOostrom2013}
\end{itemize}

Sometimes, however, I want to quote \textcquote*{vanOostrom2013}{Some Famous words}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Van Oostrom 2013 is not what we want. the V must always be capitalized.//luckily Van Oostrom 2013 will fix this for us//same for Van Oostrom, Van Oostrom (2013) and even (Van Oostrom 2013)//but F. van Oostrom (2013). Wereld in Woorden. Amsterdam: Uitgeverij Bert Bakker]

Note that the name order with inverted names in the bibliography does not seem to follow the conventions in the Netherlands (I would expect 'Oostrom, F. van', see https://taaladvies.net/taal/advies/vraag/145/). For that you would need [How can I put a name's prefix in front in citations but *not* in the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21361/35864). A related question is at  [Prefixes in author names in references and bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/440133/35864).

It is still advisable to use the capitalised form `\Cite`, `\Parencite` at the beginning of sentences since those commands may produce more text that might be subject to capitalisation (one real-world example is "ibid.").

Comment: thx @moewe for this elegant solution. Am I correct when I say I still "need" to use `\Textcite` (and equivalents) in the beginning of a sentence in order to easily change citationstyles (should the need ever arise)

Comment: @LooselySubtle Yes, using the capitalised version at the beginning of a sentence is still preferred in case the commands print other text that might have to adjust capitalisation, for example "ibid.".

Answer (score 3):

Since there are apparently no circumstances in which you will not want the first letter capitalised, you should be able to reset the command used by `csquotes` generally:

```
\SetCiteCommand{\Parencite}
```

If you needed more fine-grained control you would need to replicate `\textcquote` with a variant that used a different cite command.

Comment: +1 For the clever workaround. As it turns out writing your own version of `csquotes`-like `\...quote` macros is not as easy as writing your own `\...cite` command (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/463165/35864).

Comment: I can only vote one answer to be correct :/ - Sorry Paul but @moewes is a little bit more elegant...

Comment: I violently disagree: @moewe's is a *lot* more elegant!