# Italic correction in own quote commands from csquotes

Tags: spacing, csquotes, italic-correction

I'm using the csquotes package and defined (with the [help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463199/45570) of this forum) three additional quotation commands for quoting ancient sources.

However, the italics correction seems to be missing. It's very visible for all three commands `\textquoteQ`, `\enquoteQ` and `\blockquoteQ` especially with big characters like the closing brackets from `\textelp` (see the red arrows in the attached picture. The spacing should be more like the other lines.).

I've tried to include the italics correction `\/` manually like `\newcommand{\enquoteQ}[1]{{\setquotestyle{ancientquote}\enquote{#1}\/}}` which works for the footnotes, but also effects e.g. the full stop which is then further apart compared to a full stop after a normal `\emph` command.

What is missing to get the italics correction back?

MWE:

```
\documentclass [fontsize=10pt,paper=238mm:168mm,pagesize,headsepline,plainheadsepline,headinclude,twoside,open=right,BCOR=5mm,DIV=14,captions=tableheading,toc=listof,toc=bibliography,numbers=noendperiod,listof=numbered,headings=optiontoheadandtoc] {scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\usepackage[french,english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=footnote-dw,xref=true,mincrossrefs=1,edsuper=true,autocite=footnote,ibidtracker=constrict,idemtracker=constrict,ibidpage=true,namefont=smallcaps,citedas=true,annotation=true,idemfont=smallcaps]{biblatex}


\usepackage[autostyle=true, german=quotes, english=british, french=guillemets]{csquotes}

\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}

 \renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\nobreakspace#1} 


 \newenvironment*{smallquote}
   {\quote\small}
   {\endquote}

  \SetBlockEnvironment{smallquote}


\newtoggle{csq@qquote}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{%
  \leavevmode
  \begingroup
  \iftoggle{csq@qquote}
    {\itshape}
    {\advance\csq@qlevel\@ne
     \llap{\csq@thequote@oopen}}%
  #1%
  \iftoggle{csq@qquote}
    {}
    {\csq@thequote@oclose}%
  \endgroup
  #2#4#3}

\let\csqq@blockquote\blockquote

\renewcommand{\blockquote}{\togglefalse{csq@qquote}\csqq@blockquote}
\newcommand{\blockquoteQ}{\toggletrue{csq@qquote}\csqq@blockquote}
\makeatother


\DeclareQuoteStyle{ancientquote}[\itshape][\itshape]{}{}[0.05em]{}{}
\newcommand{\textquoteQ}[2]{{\setquotestyle{ancientquote}\textquote[#1][]{#2}}}
\newcommand{\enquoteQ}[1]{{\setquotestyle{ancientquote}\enquote{#1}}}


\begin{filecontents*}{MWE.bib}
@Collection{Test,
    editor = {Cornelisse, J. W.},
    title = {Rocket Propulsion and Spaceflight Dynamics},
    year = {1979},
        gender  = {sm},
    publisher = {Pitman},
        url = {https://google.com}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\bibliography{MWE.bib}


\begin{document}

\emph{A normal italic text with a footnote \textelp{}}\footnote{Test}

\emph{A normal italic text with a full stop \textelp{}}.


\enquote{An normal inline quotation with a footnote \textelp{}}\footnote{Test}

\enquote{An normal inline quotation with a full stop \textelp{}}.

\textquote[{\autocite{Test}}]{An normal formal inline quotation with a footnote \textelp{}}


\enquoteQ{An ancient inline quotation with a footnote \textelp{}}\footnote{Test}

\enquoteQ{An ancient inline quotation with a full stop \textelp{}}.

\textquoteQ{{\autocite{Test}}}{An ancient formal inline quotation with a footnote \textelp{}}



\blockquote[{\autocite{Test}}]{A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote \textelp{}}

\blockquoteQ[{\autocite{Test}}]{An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote \textelp{}}

\end{document}
```

[image: Missing italic correction]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `\/` as end "quote":

```
\documentclass [fontsize=10pt,paper=238mm:168mm,pagesize,headsepline,plainheadsepline,headinclude,twoside,open=right,BCOR=5mm,DIV=14,captions=tableheading,toc=listof,toc=bibliography,numbers=noendperiod,listof=numbered,headings=optiontoheadandtoc] {scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[french,english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=footnote-dw,xref=true,mincrossrefs=1,edsuper=true,autocite=footnote,ibidtracker=constrict,idemtracker=constrict,ibidpage=true,namefont=smallcaps,citedas=true,annotation=true,idemfont=smallcaps]{biblatex}


\usepackage[autostyle=true, german=quotes, english=british, french=guillemets]{csquotes}

\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}

 \renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\nobreakspace#1}


 \newenvironment*{smallquote}
   {\quote\small}
   {\endquote}

  \SetBlockEnvironment{smallquote}


\newtoggle{csq@qquote}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{%
  \leavevmode
  \begingroup
  \iftoggle{csq@qquote}
    {\itshape}
    {\advance\csq@qlevel\@ne
     \llap{\csq@thequote@oopen}}%
  #1%
  \iftoggle{csq@qquote}
    {\/}
    {\csq@thequote@oclose}%
  \endgroup
  #2#4#3}

\let\csqq@blockquote\blockquote

\renewcommand{\blockquote}{\togglefalse{csq@qquote}\csqq@blockquote}
\newcommand{\blockquoteQ}{\toggletrue{csq@qquote}\csqq@blockquote}
\makeatother


\DeclareQuoteStyle{ancientquote}[\itshape][\itshape]{}{\/}[0.05em]{}{\/}
\newcommand{\textquoteQ}[2]{{\setquotestyle{ancientquote}\textquote[#1][]{#2}}}
\newcommand{\enquoteQ}[1]{{\setquotestyle{ancientquote}\enquote{#1}}}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}

\emph{A normal italic text with a footnote \textelp{}}\footnote{Test}

\emph{A normal italic text with a full stop \textelp{}}.


\enquote{An normal inline quotation with a footnote \textelp{}}\footnote{Test}

\enquote{An normal inline quotation with a full stop \textelp{}}.

\textquote[{\autocite{doody}}]{An normal formal inline quotation with a footnote \textelp{}}


\enquoteQ{An ancient inline quotation with a footnote \textelp{}}\footnote{Test}

\enquoteQ{An ancient inline quotation with a full stop \textelp{}}.

\enquoteQ{An ancient inline quotation with a full stop}.


\textquoteQ{{\autocite{doody}}}{An ancient formal inline quotation with a footnote \textelp{}}



\blockquote[{\autocite{doody}}]{A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote A normal blockquote \textelp{}}

\blockquoteQ[{\autocite{doody}}]{An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote An ancient blockquote \textelp{}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. One more question if you look at the 2nd (\emph{...}) and 7th (\enquoteQ{...}) line of the MWE I have the impression that there is a bit more spacing between the square bracket and the final full stop in the 7th line than in the 2nd line after your proposed modifications. Is it possible that ´\emph´ does some magic if the character which follows is a full stop?