# Footnotemark is italicized in scrbook when inside italicized text

Tags: footnotes, koma-script, italic, scrbook

I noticed that with the scrbook class a footnote mark within an italicized text gets also italicized (see MWE1).

With the book class instead the footnote mark is upright which is I think the better behavior (see MWE2).

My question is how to get the behavior of MWE2 for the scrbook class?
Please note that I can't just interrupt the \textit command then use the footnote and then repeat with \textit, because I also have quite complicated quotation environments (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463199/45570)) with the same problem which cannot be interrupted that easily.

MWE1

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\textit{Some text\footnote{Footnote text} and further text\footnote{Other footnote text}}.
\end{document}
```

MWE2

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\textit{Some text\footnote{Footnote text} and further text\footnote{Other footnote text}}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```latex
\setkomafont{footnotereference}{\normalfont}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\setkomafont{footnotereference}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\textit{Some text\footnote{Footnote text} and further text\footnote{Other footnote text}}.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]